# Fetch not working on first click of onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When I use modalOpen in a onClick function it wont fetch api on the 1st click causing the code to break but it will on 2nd click what can cause it

```js
// get anime result and push to modal function

const modalAnime = async () => {
  const { data } = await fetch(`${base_url}/anime/${animeId}`)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  SetAnimeModalData(data);
};
```

I am trying to get the fetch to work on the first click but it doesn't until second or third click

```jsx
const modalOpen = (event) => {
  SetAnimeId(event.currentTarget.id);
  SetModalVisible(true);

  modalAnime();
  console.log(animeId);
};
const modalClose = () => {
  SetModalVisible(false);
  SetAnimeId("");
};

return (
  <div className="app">
    <Header
      searchAnime={searchAnime}
      search={search}
      SetSearch={SetSearch}
      mostPopular={mostPopular}
      topRated={topRated}
    />
    {loadingState ? (
      <ResultLoading />
    ) : (
      <Results
        animeResults={animeResults}
        topRated={topRated}
        mostPopular={mostPopular}
        modalOpen={modalOpen}
      />
    )}
    {modalVisible ? <AnimeInfoModal modalClose={modalClose} /> : <></>}
  </div>
);
```

the modal opens fine but the ID isn't captured until the second or third click

I have more code but Stack Overflow won't let me add it.

Answer (score 0):

`SetAnimeId()` won't update the `animeId` state property until the next render cycle. Seems like you should only update the *visible* and `animeId` states after you've fetched data.

You should also check for request failures by checking the [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property.

```js
// this could be defined outside your component
const fetchAnime = async (animeId) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${base_url}/anime/${animeId}`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw res;
  }

  return (await res.json()).data;
};
```

```js
const modalOpen = async ({ currentTarget: { id } }) => {
  // Await data fetching then set all new state values
  SetAnimeModalData(await fetchAnime(id));
  SetAnimeId(id);
  SetModalVisible(true);
};
```

Comment: thnaks but this didnt work the first click always returns an empty object and then breaks the modal code

Comment: @AaqeebHussain I've updated my answer with something I think should work with your modal code